# what is the best way to populate liked status for a feed in feed list when feed is liked by millions

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm trying to create a social portal like facebook or instagram where user creates feeds and other users likes that. 
I'm using Relational DB Mysql for storing data.

**My question :**

when a user requests feed list and say server returns list of 50 feeds then feed should also has like status (stating whether user has liked that particular feed). Now if a feed has millions of liker then searching whether requester has liked that feed will take considerable amount of time and since i have to return 50 such feeds then definitely it'll take huge amount of time for populating feed list.

So far I'm doing this using a stored procedure.

I have a user table, a feed table and likers table (which contains feed_id and User_id).
My stored procedure usage IN query to populates liked status. This is working since i have very few number of likers. But this will take a long time as likers will increase.

What is the best way to approach it?

Comment: As long as you've got proper indexes, this should remain pretty performant. That said, it's generally best to worry about problems caused by having millions of users when you're actually starting to *get* millions of users. Premature optimization wastes a lot of priceless effort early on.

Comment: Are your tables reasonably indexed? Why does your stored procedure iterate instead of just joining the tables on an indexed column? Can you provide your table indexes and your SP code? I suspect there might be some low-hanging fruit here before getting into more complicated performance solutions.

Comment: my bad, it doesn't iterate but usage IN query, I'll be adding SP by evening today. I have indexes only on primary keys so, its in Feed_ID, USER_ID and on both column of likers table which i think should be sufficient.

Comment: @ceejayoz yes, currently its working well, but I wanna know solution of million users for both knowledge purpose and being prepared for situation

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't have suitable indexes; millions of rows should not be a big deal.

```
PRIMARY KEY(feed_id, User_id),
INDEX(User_id, feed_id)
```

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the SQL statements accessing the table; there could be other tips for us to supply.